# Gradient Estimates for semi-linear equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

i would like to know because the term $D_{z}f|Du|^{2}$ appears in the proof of gradient estimate

[image]

I supppose that $D_{z}f|Du|^{2} = 0$, since $f$ is a function of $(x,u) \in \Omega$